# Controlling none windows applications\windows with python

Tags: python, qt, pyside, autoit, nswindowcontroller

I need to control a non windows application (presuming Java) with python. Autoit and pywinauto did not do the trick. The application was not created with Qt so pyqt\pyside are irrelevant, right?

Please direct me to a python module that will enable button clicks, fields input etc.

Thanks!

Comment: AutoIt should just work fine for non Windows windows. Maybe i could help you make it work but we lack information. Also have you allready written some code? Share it with us.

Comment: It needs to be a cross platform interface. Program runs on MAC, Win and Linux so Autoit does not cover all OS.

I would like to stay with python and list the windows objects and work with them - click, enter text, etc.

Comment: Ohh i see.. thats what he ment with non windows application. Sorry, understood your question wrong. Not so familiar with Python, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try  [pyautogui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) , I'm not sure whether it works with your non windows application

Comment: pyautogui seem to give the required functionality. thanks again!!